# What X.509v3 extensions are required for JAR signature to verify?

Tags: jar, digital-signature, x509

Oracle documentation [states](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#Signature_Validation) that "*A successful JAR file verification occurs if the signature(s) are valid [...]*" without detailing further what means "valid".

Being "valid" requires, among other things, a "correct" related X.509 certificate. "Correct" here would involve e.g. correct validity period and suitable X.509v3 extensions (if present).

My question is about the latter. **What X.509v3 extension combinations does Oracle require for the JAR signature to verify?**

For example, I'd expect that **if** `ExtendedKeyUsage` extension is present, **then** it must contain `CodeSigning` bit.

I'm writing a non-Java library to verify JARs, and I was not able to find a specification for this.

Comment: May be the code of the verify part of `jarsigner` can help you a bit: [verifyJar method of sun.security.tools.jarsigner.Main](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/sun/security/tools/jarsigner/Main.java#Main.verifyJar%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: I think the certificate I retrieved from Oracle doesn't have all that many extensions etc. Note that the certificate needs to have been *signed by Oracle*; that's kind of all the validation that is required. If you want to know what is signed: take a signed .jar file, unzip, retrieve the certificate and parse it, e.g. with `openssl parse`. You can do the similar thing with the certificate signing request (CSR) generated by the `signtool`.\